# How to display multiple EditText inputs after pressing Button in one TextView?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I'm in the beginning of my learning how to make apps. I want to make an app which should display randomized inputted tasks to do for the user. Firstly user should choose how many tasks would like to create and then write down tasks in EditText. I am able to create particular amount of EditText but I have no clue how to display all EditText input after pressing button. I have many versions of the code but non of them work. I got stuck and I need advice.

Here is one of my code version for the second activity.

```
public class TaskActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

LinearLayout containerLayout;
TextView receiverTV;
TextView tv;
TextView displayTaskTv;

EditText et;

Button btn;
Button randomTaskBtn;

int i = 0;
int size;

String inputEditText;
String inputTextView;

String stringsEt[];
String stringsTv [];


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_task);
    containerLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_layout);


    receiverTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.receiver_textView);


    Intent intent = getIntent();
    int number = intent.getIntExtra("Number", defaultValue);
    receiverTV.setText("You have chosen to add: " + number + " tasks!");

    createEtTvBtn(number);
    createBtn();
    createTextView();

}

public void createEtTvBtn(int number) {

    for (i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
        tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText("Task nr: " + i);
        tv.setPadding(16, 16, 16, 16);
        tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#008b50"));
        tv.setTextSize(20);
        tv.setId(i + value);
        containerLayout.addView(tv);


        et = new EditText(this);
        et.setHint("Enter task nr: " + i);
        et.setId(i + value);
        et.setLines(2);
        containerLayout.addView(et);

        btn = new Button(this);
        btn.setText("Confirm task nr: " + i);
        btn.setId(i + value);
        containerLayout.addView(btn);

        final List<EditText> allEditText = new ArrayList<EditText>();
        final List<TextView>allTextView = new ArrayList<TextView>();
        final List<Button>allButton = new ArrayList<Button>();

        String[] stringsEditText = new String[(allEditText.size())];
        String[] stringsTextView = new String[(allTextView.size())];
        String[] stringsBtn = new String[(allButton.size())];


        for(int i=0; i < allEditText.size(); i++){
            stringsEditText[i] = allEditText.get(i).getText().toString();

        }
        for (int i=0; i < allTextView.size(); i++) {
            stringsTextView[i] = allTextView.get(i).getText().toString();
            size = allTextView.get(i).getText().toString().length();
        }
        for(int i=0; i < allButton.size(); i++){
            stringsBtn[i] = allButton.get(i).getText().toString();

        }

        allTextView.add(tv);

        allEditText.add(et);

        allButton.add(btn);

        allButton.get(0).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                inputEditText = allEditText.get(0).getText().toString();
                stringsEt = new String[] {allEditText.get(0).getText().toString()};


                if (inputEditText.length() > 0) {
                allTextView.get(0).setText(inputEditText);

                    allEditText.add(allEditText.get(0));
                    allEditText.get(0).setText("");

                    }
                    else if (inputEditText.length() ==0){
                    Toast.makeText(TaskActivity.this, "You need to write down your task", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                inputTextView = allTextView.get(0).getText().toString();
                stringsTv = new String[] {allTextView.get(0).getText().toString()};
                if (inputTextView.length() > 0) {
                    allTextView.get(0).getText();
                    allTextView.add(allTextView.get(0));
                }
            }
        });

    }
}

    private Button createBtn() {
    randomTaskBtn = new Button(this);
    randomTaskBtn.setText("Task");
    containerLayout.addView(randomTaskBtn);

        randomTaskBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


            double luckyTask = Math.random();
            luckyTask *=size;
            int luckyIndex = (int)luckyTask;
            displayTaskTv.setText(stringsTv[luckyIndex]);
                }
        });
        return randomTaskBtn;

            }
    private TextView createTextView() {
    displayTaskTv = new TextView(this);
    displayTaskTv.setTextSize(20);
    displayTaskTv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#dd2626"));
    displayTaskTv.setText("");
    containerLayout.addView(displayTaskTv);
        return displayTaskTv;

}

}
```

Thank you for any constructive advices.

I am sure my code is big mess. I wanted to created more methods but I didn't succeed.

Comment: you want to create EditText and button dynamically and get text by clicking on each button that assign to specific editText? if i get it correct tell me to continue

Comment: yes, it's right. After clicking confirm task button I am able to display EditText input in TextView. I would like to add one more button which will display text from all Text Views in one new TextView in new Activity. After reaching that level I would like to randomly display one of the tasks.

Comment: I want to create EditText programmatically because amount of EditText depends on the user. The user chooses how many tasks would like to add. Each task is separate EditText. In MainActivity user can choose amount of tasks. In TaskActivity I create EditText, TextView and Button based on selected by the user number. I can take input from EditText and display it in TextView by pressing button. Unfortunately I am losing my hope that I can display text from all EditText in one TextView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you should do

Step 1 - 
Create multiple EditTexts and store each one of them in an `ArrayList` say `myEditTextList`.

Step 2- Take data from all edit texts

```
String str = ""
for(EditText et: myEditTextList) {
   str += et.getText().toString();
}
```

Step 3- Display data in `str` wherever you want.

Comment: Thank you! I will try to do it in a moment

Comment: I made a simple version of my app and your code is really working. Thank you one more time.

Comment: Hi Abhishek, can I ask you one more question?

Comment: @Marzena sure! please accept this answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: I would like to save EditText input. Should I use for that SharedPreferences?

Comment: Yes, you may use shared preferences.